# controllerDidChangeContent index beyond bounds

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know my question is a little bit vague, but I need some clues/ideas were could be the problem. I tried everything and I can not find the problem.

I have used `NSFetchedResultsController` with `UITableView` for a couple of times and have never experience this kind of problem. I have a table view, and I connected it with core data using `NSFetchedResultsController`. I create `NSFetchedResultsController` like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:_database.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                          initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:_database.managedObjectContext
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                          cacheName:nil];
```

At one point when there are more records than table view can display in one screen and user tries to scroll down to the bottom of the table view, crash happens.

Scenario:

1) I create `insertNewObjectForEntityName` and save context

2) I receive delegate call `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath` with type `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`

3) I try to scroll down to the bottom of the table, I get an error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6] with userInfo (null)

The same crash also sometimes happens, if a user opens an app and tries to scroll to the bottom/top of the list. I opened sqlite file and all records are there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception in the delegate?

Comment: Are you using a single ManagedObjectContext ? is _database.managedObjectContext the same context your using when you add extra data when user scrolls ?

Comment: Yes, the exception is happening on [self.tableView endUpdates] with reason "-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]". I am not sure what is 7 though, because I have more items in the list.

Comment: Since your tableView is hooked up to FRC , the exception happens when there is extra data but FRC.fetchedObjects does not update its content. After inserting new data call `[FRC performFetch]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help. After debugging I realised that there was a logic error. Saving of the managed object context was triggered at the moment of scrolling, that caused the error. I am not sure why this is not allowed (maybe someone can explain). I removed saving and now everything works as it should. Thanks again!

Comment: FRC monitors the Context if any new objects are added , as soon as a save is called it assumes new objects were added and goes and fetches all the objects in the context and tries to update the table.